# Wordpress: Use title (slug) in hashed URL instead of post ID

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, slug

I am developing a WordPress site where I hope to load the content using ajax. I seem to have it working although I'm not too sure how good my code is! My issue is that I would like the hash to display the post title (slug) in the URL (address bar) instead of the post ID but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Can anyone offer some advice, thanks

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        $(".post-pop").click(function(){
            var post_url = $(this).attr("href");
            var post_id = $(this).attr("rel");
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
            $("#your_post_here").load("http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; ?>/blog-post/",{id:post_id});
            window.location.hash = post_id;
            return false;
        });
        if(document.location.hash!='') {
            var hashVal = window.location.hash.substring(1);
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 0);
            $("#your_post_here").load("http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; ?>/blog-post/",{id:hashVal});
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: displayed where? in the address bar?

Comment: Yes in the address bar... Sorry if I wasn't clear, I wrote that at 3am after a long day!

Comment: html5 has a standard way to do this, see http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate

Comment: Read about history.js on SO, it will be useful in your case.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track